# Using an OracleDataSource in Hibernate JPA in J2SE environment

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jdbc

Is it possible to configure Hibernate/JPA to use an OracleDataSource in a standalone environment? More specifically, what I want to do is configure the oracle implicit connection cache through the persistence.xml file. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance
Brian

Answer (score 1):

I recently solved a similar problem in a JSE application using MySQL. As in your case I needed it to use an existing connection provider.

In my case I used [Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/). This connection pooling framework allows me to create a connection pool over a data source and then register the pool under a fake driver name which you can use in your JPA configuration in the persistence.xml file.

This is how I did it. First I registered a connection pool based on the original data source and also I registered a fake driver for this given pool.

```
private ObjectPool getNewConnectionPool(DataSource mySqlDataSource) {
    try {
        GenericObjectPool pool = new GenericObjectPool(null, 10); 
        pool.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        ConnectionFactory factory = new DataSourceConnectionFactory(mySqlDataSource);
        PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(factory, pool, null, "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL", false, true);
        Class.forName("org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver");
        PoolingDriver driver = (PoolingDriver) DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:");
        driver.registerPool("myPool", pool);
        return poolableConnectionFactory.getPool();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to initialize connetion pooling", e);
    }
}
```

Then, instead of using the original data source, from this point on I continue to use the pooled data source.

```
DataSource dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(getNewConnectionPool(mySqlDataSource));
```

Up to this point, you have a functional data source based on the original one from which you could obtain connections. You can also obtain connections through a fake driver registered for this pool, and these would also come from the original data source.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:myPool");
```

But not only for that, you could use this URL in your persistence.xml file to configure the source of your connections for JPA or in the properties that you provide to your EntityManagerFactory when you create it.

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put("javax.persistence.provider", "org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:myPool");
this.entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myUnit", properties);
this.entityManager = this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

Using this JDBC URL you now can have access to the connections in the pool and through it, to the original data source.